# Unable to install Imagemagick on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, imagemagick, apt-get

I've got a virtual machine running on Ubuntu 12.10. When I try to run

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

I get several 404 errors:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main libcups2 amd64 1.6.1-0ubuntu11.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libcupsimage2 amd64 1.6.1-0ubuntu11.5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main libtiff5 amd64 4.0.2-1ubuntu2.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcups2_1.6.1-0ubuntu11.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libcupsimage2_1.6.1-0ubuntu11.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups/libtiff5_4.0.2-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried to run `apt-get` with `--fix-missing` but that didn't solve the 404 errors.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix these 404's?

Comment: are you sure your networking is operating properly?  Is your firewall preventing access to this IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure my network is operating properly, and I'm getting response when I ping these IP addresses.

Comment: what about your firewall (or your companies)?  You can ping an address without being able to access specific ports you realize?  Home system or work system?

Comment: I'm not sure if my firewall blocks these requests. I don't know how to check that :( But I really doubt that's the issue because I get 404 errors, not timeouts or something. 
The system is a Digital Ocean droplet (read: virtual machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files that apt-get is asking are not present in that repository.
If you check with a browser in `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cups`/ (e.g.)
you do not find `libcups2_1.6.1-0ubuntu11.5_amd64.deb`.

Try to do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and after

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing
```

Comment: Thanks! `apt-get update` did the trick!

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it can be useful for other people, feel you free to up the answer ;-). However I'm enquiring now, can you tell me if it was a ready image of Ubuntu for Virutalbox?

Comment: It was a out-of-the-box ready made install of Ubuntu.

Comment: From [here](http://virtualboxes.org/images/ubuntu/) you can download a version more recent if you have other problems.